# Node.js - Reading socket input as a whole word

Tags: node.js, sockets

I use Node on Windows, and when I run the example code, I get the "data" character by character, instead of the entire word.

I realize that's the way it SHOULD work - however the course I'm taking claims it's supposed to read "data" as a word (like "readline" module "question" works).

For example:

```
 var net = require('net');
 var server = net.createServer(function(socket){    
        socket.on('data', function(data){
            console.log("this is what the user wrote: " + data);
        }); 
    });

server.listen(888,"127.0.0.1");
```

will echo the word "hello" like this:
h
e
l
l
o
instead of the expected "hello"

My setup is a server on port 888 and I telnet this port.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using socket.io module?

Comment: The course is wrong then, you shouldn't assume that a data chunk will be any specific size for streams (with objectMode this isn't true of course, but that is different).

Comment: @Paramore thanks for your comment, updated the full code - I don't user socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the question right then this code should work

```
 var net = require('net');
 var server = net.createServer(function(socket){ 
    var fulldata=''; 
    socket.on('data', function(data){

        fulldata+=data;
        if(data==" "){ console.log("this is what the user wrote: " + fulldata); fulldata='';}
    });

});

server.listen(23,"127.0.0.1");
```